# MediaRecorder recording remote stream using VP9 codec doesn't work

Tags: webrtc, mediarecorder, vp9

I tried to use MediaRecorder to record remote video stream using codec VP9, but I can only get a video that cannot play.

Env: latest Chrome (105.0.5195.127).

The stream is so common.

```
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
      video: {
        width: { ideal: 9999 },
        height: { ideal: 9999 }
      },
      audio: false
    });
```

For auto record, I use `setTimeout` to stop MediaRecorder. `downloadBlob` uses `<a>` to download blob as `.webm` file, I think this is not where the problem lies.

```
export function record(stream, duration) {
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
    mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'
  });

  const chunks = [];
  recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
    if (e.data.size > 0) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
  };
  recorder.onstop = () => {
    downloadBlob(
      new Blob(chunks, {
        type: chunks[0].type
      }),
      `filename.webm`
    );
  };

  recorder.start();

  setTimeout(() => {
    recorder.stop();
  }, duration);
}
```

I trigger `record(localStream)` after `pc.addTrack` and `transceiver.setCodecPreferences` (If required, I can also provide these codes), and localStream can be recorded correctly, which means I can play it in PotPlayer and the codec shows VP90.

However, when I trigger `record(remoteStream)` in `pc.ontrack`, I cannot play the downloaded video. By the way, the video can correctly show by `<video>`.

I noticed that when I use `console.log(e.data.size)` in `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable`, recording local stream shows 12255987 (a large number) and recording remote stream only shows 3501. I think this is the real problem, but I can't solve it.

---

By the way, I used to encounter a problem about `addIceCandidate`. The receiver pc will receive candidate message before set remote desc, so I create a queue at the sender side to make sure both sides set remote&local desc before exchange ICE candidate. I have no idea if this is a stupid operation.

```
const candidateQueue = [];
this.pc.onicecandidate = e => {
  if (e.candidate) {
    candidateQueue.push(e.candidate);
    if (this.pc.currentRemoteDescription) {
      candidateQueue.forEach(c =>
        this.server.send('candidate', JSON.stringify(c))
      );
      candidateQueue.length = 0;
    }
  }
};
```

---

New progress! If I remove `transceiver.setCodecPreferences`, recorder can record VP9 codec video correctly. However, in my opinion, the VP9 codec just takes place while recording, `RTCPeerConnection` still use VP8 to transmit video info. Thus I cannot achieve my goal to measure video quality while transmitting by different codecs.

Answer (score 0):

New progress! Problem solved.
If you don't pass mimeType to MediaRecorder and don't pass type to Blob, then video can be correctly recorded, and the codec shows VP9.
I wonder if someone can tell me why. I will also try to read the source code and share my opnion later.